# Mediawiki Math formula's font size is too small

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have recently upgraded Mediawiki to 1.18.0. After that we had faced issue with Math syntax(Functions). I have requested my IT team to install relevant software/package and it started working fine. I am generating some math formula's as images and some as text. The text formula's are very small.

How do I increase the math generated formula's font?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the CSS that controls Math is in `/skins/common/shared.css`.  You should be able to make adjustments to `font-size`.

Comment: Could it therefore also be a mistake in MediaWiki:Common.css? What entry needs to be checked?